# YA where family returns to Arthurian times, oblivious mother keeps asking for cream tea

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult, arthurian

Helping out on a Twitter request, original [here](https://twitter.com/Nicole_Cliffe/status/930510206403952640).

YA book. A family visiting a historic castle while on a trip gets separated and falls through time into King Arthur times. The mom doesn't realize they've gone back, keeps being like “I was told there would be a cream tea” and literally never figures it out.

The cream tea is a VITAL detail, unquestionably present.

Twitter request states she's been looking for this book for ~20 years. And that:

> DISCLAIMER: you will want to say “Half Magic” by Edward Eager, but it is not.

Comment: Aside from an Arthurian setting, this doesn't really have much in common with Half Magic anyway.

Comment: @user14111, "keeps being like" almost certainly means "keeps saying things similar to"; "gets separated" almost certainly means "gets separated from the rest of the tour group".